# css animation inside of animation is not working

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I am learning JavaScript and trying to make a website.

I made a page with animation css that slides into home page when click a icon.
inside the page, there is unordered list, and I want them to slide in respectively as well.

When I made a page, I made a function in addEventListner, and the class that has about animation is added/ removed by clicking. 
and It worked so I did same to the unordered list, but it does not work.

this is part of my HTML

```
<nav class="nav"><img class="menu-icon1" src="menu.png"></nav>
<body>

<div class="home">

    <div class="first-page-container">
    this is a main page
    </div>
    <div class="menu hidden-page">
        <nav class="nav"><img class="menu-icon2" src="menu.png"></nav>
        <div class="menu-list-wrapper">
            <ul class="menu-list">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

this is my css

```
.hidden-page{
    display: none;
}

.visible{
    display: block;
    animation-name: openmenubar;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.closeBar{
    animation-name: closemenubar;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes openmenubar {
    0% {opacity: 0; right: -100%}
    100% {opacity: 1; right: 0;}
}

@keyframes closemenubar {
    0% {opacity: 1; right: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0; right: -100;}
}
/*the above animations are working*/

.visible-item1 {
    display: block;
    animation-name: listitem1;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes listitem1 {
    0% {opacity: 9; right: -1000px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; right: 0;} 
}

/*I have listitem2-3 in my code too*/
```

and finally, this is my js code

```
const menuOpenBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-icon1');
const menuBar = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-icon2');
const menulistItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

const menuOpenHandler = function(){
    menuBar.classList.remove('closeBar');
    menuBar.classList.remove('hidden-page');
    menuBar.classList.add('visible');
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < menulistItems.length; i++ ){
        menulistItems[i].classList.add(`visible-item${i + 1}`);
    };//this code adds class name but animation is not working

};

const menuCloseHandler = function(){
    menuBar.classList.add('closeBar');
    menuBar.classList.remove('visible');
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < menulistItems.length; i++ ){
        menulistItems[i].classList.remove(`visible-item${i + 1}`);
    };//this code adds class name but animation is not working
    setTimeout(()=>{menuBar.classList.add('hidden-page');}, 1000);
};

menuOpenBtn.addEventListener('click', menuOpenHandler);
menuCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', menuCloseHandler);
```

I really appreciate if you can answer with vanilla JavaScript. Thank you so much:)

Comment: There's a problem with your code, const menuOpenBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-icon1'); In your HTML is missing the element with class "menu-icon1". Please check and avoid placing elements based on images which don't exist.

Comment: Oops I forgot to add them. Thank you for letting me know!